# How to push an object into local .json in Angular?

Tags: json, angularjs, push

As the title suggests, how do I update my .json file after a user inputs stuff? I can do a .get and display the json contents but I'm lost on how to push/update my json.

Here's my factory service:

```
angular.module('services', [])
    .factory('localpolls', ['$http', function($http){
        return {
            get: function(callback){
                $http.get('polls/polls.json').success(function(data){
                    callback(data);
                });
            }
        };

    }]);
```

Here's the part of my controller for the view I'm working in:

```
angular.module('controllers')
        .controller('pollCtrl', ['$scope', 'localpolls', function ($scope, localpolls){

        localpolls.get(function(data){
            $scope.polls = data;
        });

$scope.question = {pollQuestion:''}
$scope.responses = [
        {
            response: ""
        },      
        {
            response: ""
        },      
        {
            response: ""
        },      
        {
            response: ""
        }];

$scope.submitPost = function (){
    if(confirm('Create Poll?')){
        $scope.polls.push($scope.question, $scope.responses);
        $scope.responses = [
        {response: ""},     
        {response: ""}, 
        {response: ""},     
        {response: ""}];
        $scope.question = {pollQuestion: ''};


    }else{
        return;
    };


};
```

You can see in my submit post I have the $scope.polls.push but this doesn't update the .json  with the user input object. Am I doing this wrong? What do I need to do?

Comment: This can only be achieved via server side logic. You can create an API for that and call the API in AngularJS.

Comment: You mean with $http.post? I Feel like that's what i'm supposed to use but don't exactly know how. I know I probably should put it into my service but I don't know exactly how.  btw the json file is a local .json file

Comment: you cant do that with angular,it's not its concern.