# pushing data to local .json file via $http service in angular?

Tags: json, angularjs, http, service

Is it possible to push data to a local json file stored in my app folder using the $http service?

I've tried fiddling around with $http.post/.get and can't find a way to save/push new data into my local .json file.

Comment: What server implementation are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to push an object into local .json in Angular?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025155/how-to-push-an-object-into-local-json-in-angular)

Comment: Server implementation? None, I'm not hooking up a backend or anything. The .json is in a local folder 'polls/polls.json' where the index.html file. Is there anyway to push data there? Or does it have to be a remote service?

Comment: There's no easy way to write to a file system from a browser. It would be a MAJOR security flaw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is a client side program and therefore has no ability to modify files on your server (if you're just playing with directories on your local machine, for all intents and purposes, the local machine is your server.) Its only concern is client side logic.  You need some type of server backend to do this.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give firebase a try.